# Liferay PermissionChecker returns guest's permissions instead of site member's

Tags: java, jsf, permissions, liferay, liferay-6

I am developing a JSF portlet in Liferay-6.2 and I'm setting up permissions. I have created my `default.xml` file and I think it is working since it saves in the database the correct permissions. Also I think `resourceLocalService.addResources(...)` is working since it also saves in the database the correct rows, anyway I am doing it as Administrator, I don't know if it has something to do with my problem.

My problem is when I try to check the permission for a site member, it denies the permission as it was a guest.

Here is the significant part of my `default.xml`

```
<model-resource>
    <model-name>org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model</model-name>
    <portlet-ref>
        <portlet-name>tool-builder</portlet-name>
    </portlet-ref>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>ADD_TOOL_DEF</action-key>
            <action-key>ADD_TOOL_INSTANCE</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults>
            <action-key>ADD_TOOL_INSTANCE</action-key>
        </site-member-defaults>
        <guest-defaults />
        <guest-unsupported>
            <action-key>ADD_TOOL_DEF</action-key>
            <action-key>ADD_TOOL_INSTANCE</action-key>
        </guest-unsupported>
    </permissions>
</model-resource>
```

Which as result I suppose it saves these two rows in the ResourceAction table:

```
| resourceActionId | name                              | actionId          | bitwiseValue |
|             2705 | org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model | ADD_TOOL_DEF      |            2 |
|             2706 | org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model | ADD_TOOL_INSTANCE |            4 |
|             2707 | org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model | PERMISSIONS       |            4 |
```

When I save my resource I do

```
User user = userPersistence.findByPrimaryKey(liferayFacesContext.getUserId());

resourceLocalService.addResources(user.getCompanyId(),
                toolDefDBE.getGroupId(),
                liferayFacesContext.getScopeGroupId(),
                "org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model",
                toolDef.getToolDefId(), false, true, true);
```

Which, if I'm not wrong, saves this in the database:

```
| resourcePermissionId | companyId | name                              | primKey | roleId | ownerId | actionIds |
|                 6101 |     10154 | org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model |    5201 |  10163 |   10158 |        14 |
|                 6102 |     10154 | org.lrc.liferay.toolbuilder.model |    5201 |  10170 |       0 |         4 |
```

According to Role_ table, 10163 is the Owner's roleId and 10170 is the Site member's roleId

Finally, when I want to check the permission I have this is my requestBean:

```
public Boolean getHasAddPermission() {
    if (this.hasAddPermission == null) {
        LiferayFacesContext liferayFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance();
        long scopeGroupId = liferayFacesContext.getScopeGroupId();
        System.out.println("El scopeGroupId es " + scopeGroupId);
        this.hasAddPermission = liferayFacesContext.getThemeDisplay().getPermissionChecker().hasPermission
                (scopeGroupId, ToolSession.MODEL, toolSession.getToolDef().getToolDefDBEId(), "ADD_TOOL_INSTANCE");
    }
    return this.hasAddPermission;
}
```

But for a site member it returns me false instead of true. Anyone does know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! The problem was that the user was not site member. Liferay makes a difference between logged users and site members. To be a site member you must assign the new users a role of that site by default or assign it later with the site owner user